# How to Set fillColor, StrokeWidth and StrokeColor of vector drawable programatically in Android

Tags: java, android, vector

I have searched a lot about changing fillColor , strokeColor and strokeWidth of a vector drawable but didn't found anything.

This is the vector drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="300"
android:viewportHeight="300"
android:width="300dp"
android:height="300dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M150.412,10.422999999999973,C227.47,10.422999999999973,289.93100000000004,72.81,289.93100000000004,149.771,C289.93100000000004,226.73,227.47,289.119,150.412,289.119,C73.36,289.119,10.893,226.73,10.893,149.771,C10.893,72.81,73.36,10.422999999999973,150.412,10.422999999999973z"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeColor="#010101"
    android:strokeMiterLimit="10" />
```

If I want to Change its FillColor, StrokeColor and StrokeWidth using Xml then code for that will be the following one:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="300"
android:viewportHeight="300"
android:width="300dp"
android:height="300dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M150.412,10.422999999999973,C227.47,10.422999999999973,289.93100000000004,72.81,289.93100000000004,149.771,C289.93100000000004,226.73,227.47,289.119,150.412,289.119,C73.36,289.119,10.893,226.73,10.893,149.771,C10.893,72.81,73.36,10.422999999999973,150.412,10.422999999999973z"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeWidth="10"
    android:fillColor="#f50d0d"
    android:strokeColor="#f1e904"
    android:strokeMiterLimit="10" />
```

How can I achieve this programmatically via Java code?

Comment: How you do employ this vector in your project ?
do you just add to an ImageView  ?

Comment: I want to Draw this vector image on the Canvas after changes its FillColor , strokeColor and StrokeWidth using Java dynamically...

Comment: After searching, I believe there is no way to make this completely in a programmatic way..
You will have to define pre-set styles in your xml and may switch between them .
Check this [link](https://medium.com/@emmaguy/dynamically-changing-svg-colours-on-android-b026a99137ad#.s30nkau01)

Comment: Thanks @ShadyAtef ... but i have a ColorPicker from there when i select Color , changes should be Reflact on Vector Image ... for this its not sound good.. please see these links [link1](http://ajaymandrawal17.96.lt/image1.jpg) and [link2](http://ajaymandrawal17.96.lt/image2.jpg)... when i fill the Color its fill Shapes Completly not fill the interior part and StrokeColor is Change but StrokeWidth not Change.

Comment: In-fact, the only thing you can do is to apply tint over all the vector.
I even have though as reading the xml file as raw and edit & rewrite it, but that failed..

Comment: I have tried lots in this but doesn't want any success ... i have use SVG also in place of Vector but svg show this Image [link1](http://ajaymandrawal17.96.lt/image3.jpg). i have apply all the Step in this [link2](https://android-coffee.com/svg-integration-in-android-studio/)   but it still not show the image in Correct way. if svg image show correctly in android after that i want to parse the svg xml and replace  the fill , stroke and stroke-width value using java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133134/discussion-between-pankaj-negi-and-shady-atef).